# OutOfMemoryException while uploading file with System.Net.WebClient

Tags: c#, out-of-memory, httpwebrequest, webclient, webrequest

I want to upload a file with http post. The following method works fine but with files >1GB I get a `OutOfMemoryExceptions`

I found some [solutions](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/johan/2006/11/15/are-you-getting-outofmemoryexceptions-when-uploading-large-files/) based on `AllowWriteStreamBuffering` and `System.Net.WebRequest` but that doesn't seem help be in this case because I need to solve it with `System.Net.WebClient`.

The memory usage of my application when the exception is thrown is always about ~500MB

```
string file = @"C:\test.zip";
string url = @"http://foo.bar";
using (System.Net.WebClient client = new System.Net.WebClient())
{
    using (System.IO.Stream fileStream = System.IO.File.OpenRead(file))
    {
        using (System.IO.Stream requestStream = client.OpenWrite(new Uri(url), "POST"))
        {
            byte[] buffer = new byte[16 * 1024];
            int bytesRead;
            while ((bytesRead = fileStream.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length)) > 0)
            {
                requestStream.Write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

What do I need to change to avoid this error?

Comment: Have you considered using [WebClient.UploadFileAsync](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms144232(v=vs.110).aspx)?

Comment: Questions like these need to document the installed anti-malware product.  And show a stack trace with unmanaged debugging enabled.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After 1 Day of trying I found a solution for this issue.

Maybe this will help some future visitors

```
string file = @"C:\test.zip";
string url = @"http://foo.bar";
using (System.IO.Stream fileStream = System.IO.File.OpenRead(file))
{
    using (ExtendedWebClient client = new ExtendedWebClient(fileStream.Length))
    {
        using (System.IO.Stream requestStream = client.OpenWrite(new Uri(url), "POST"))
        {
            byte[] buffer = new byte[16 * 1024];
            int bytesRead;
            while ((bytesRead = fileStream.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length)) > 0)
            {
                requestStream.Write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Extended `WebClient` method

```
private class ExtendedWebClient : System.Net.WebClient
{
    public long ContentLength { get; set; }
    public ExtendedWebClient(long contentLength)
    {
        ContentLength = contentLength;
    }

    protected override System.Net.WebRequest GetWebRequest(Uri uri)
    {
        System.Net.HttpWebRequest hwr = (System.Net.HttpWebRequest)base.GetWebRequest(uri);
        hwr.AllowWriteStreamBuffering = false; //do not load the whole file into RAM
        hwr.ContentLength = ContentLength;
        return (System.Net.WebRequest)hwr;
    }
}
```